# Minion Pro not working with Tex Live 2020

Tags: minionpro

I'm trying to use Minion Pro but I get an error.

This works:

```
\IfFileExists{lucimatx.sty}{\usepackage[stdmathitalics=true,math-style=default,lucidasmallscale=true,romanfamily=bright]{lucimatx}}{\usepackage{times}}
```

This won't work:

```
\IfFileExists{MinionPro.sty}{\usepackage[mathlf,textlf,minionint,openg]{MinionPro}}{\usepackage{times}}
\IfFileExists{lucimatx.sty}{\usepackage[bb=lucida,bbscaled=1,cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}}{}
```

The error is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.475 \settowidth{\notwd}{$\not$}
```

It's problematic because this worked with Tex Live 2016 on my old laptop.

Comment: please provide a small test file and show the log, with disconnected fragments it's impossible to even guess which packages you have used, since you have guarded the `\usepackage` inside conditionals.

Comment: the idea is to load that if and only if lucimatx is installed, otherwise "bb=lucida" is meaningless

Comment: sorry I didn't notice lucida option, I deleted my 2nd comment (1st comment still applies though)

Comment: on a MWE it creates a PDF, and after commenting thing in my template I see a clash between AMS packages and Minion, as I get many "already defined" errors

Comment: as you have provided no example document and no log, I don't see how anyone will be able to debug your issue, sorry.